# How do I mount an EncFS volume at /media/username/mountpoint?

Tags: mount, mountpoint, encfs

I am using [Gnome EncFS Manager](https://launchpad.net/gencfsm) [1] on Ubuntu 13.10. If I create an encrypted folder (known as a stash) and an unencrypted mountpoint, both in the Home folder, it works. For example, `~/test-encrypted` and `~/test-mountpoint`.

However, I cannot create a mountpoint in the `/media/myusername/` folder (where USB drives and the like are mounted).

I have tried:

- mounting to a non-existent folder, e.g. `/media/myusername/newfolder`
- creating a folder `/media/myusername/createdfolder` and selecting that as a mountpoint

Both result in the following error message, even though the mountpoint is empty or does not exist:

> The mount folder is not empty.

Permissions for the folders are as follows:

```
/media$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 11 09:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Dec 11 10:26 ..
drwxr-x---+ 5 root root 4096 Dec 17 10:29 username

/media$ cd username

/media/username$ ls -la
total 17
drwxr-x---+ 5 root root 4096 Dec 17 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 11 09:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 username username 4096 Dec 11 09:49 attemptedmountpoint
drwxr-xr-x 19 username username 4096 Nov 22 11:52 workingmountpoint
```

Do I need set special permissions on the parent folder `/media/myusername` or on the new folder I want as a mountpoint? Or is there something else I should do?

[1] A GUI for EncFS mounting, currently installable via PPA from the link above.

Comment: also asked as a gencfs question https://answers.launchpad.net/gencfsm/+question/240922

Comment: What commands are you using?

Comment: @wilf for reference, I was using the "Create or import a stash" dialog (details in gencfsm help/documentation)

Comment: Just an FYI, but generally stuff in `/media/username` only needs to be set to 700 permission wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got [an answer from the developer](https://answers.launchpad.net/gencfsm/+question/240922):

> The message is misleading here. As you can see, you don't have write permissions in /media/username. That means that GEncfsM can't create the mount-points. To fix this use:
>
> ```
> sudo chown username /media/username
> ```
>
> It will then read:
>
> ```
> drwxr-x---+ 5 username root 4096 Dec 17 10:29 username
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If you want to put all mount-points per default there, you can then adjust the variable mount_dir_base in the advanced preferences to /media/$USER. GEncfsM has to be restarted after the change.