# Why does `ls -l` count more files than me?

Tags: command-line, files, ls

Apparently I cannot count. I think there are three files in `/media`

```
$ tree /media
/media
├── foo
├── onex
└── zanna
3 directories, 0 files
```

However, `ls -l` finds 12.

```
$ ls -l /media
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31 20:57 foo
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 26 06:36 onex
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 4096 Aug  7 21:17 zanna
```

And, if I do `ls -la` I get only `.` and `..` in addition to the above, but the count is `total 20`

What's the explanation?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `12` you see is not the number of files, but the number of disk blocks consumed.

From `info coreutils 'ls invocation'`:

```
 For each directory that is listed, preface the files with a line
 `total BLOCKS', where BLOCKS is the total disk allocation for all
 files in that directory.  The block size currently defaults to 1024
 bytes, but this can be overridden (*note Block size::).  The
 BLOCKS computed counts each hard link separately; this is arguably
 a deficiency.
```

The total goes from `12` to `20` when you use `ls -la` instead of `ls -l` because you are counting two additional directories: `.` and `..`.  You are using four disk blocks for each (empty) directory, so your total goes from 3 × 4  to  5 × 4.  (In all likelihood, you are using *one* disk block of 4096 bytes for each directory; as the `info` page indicates, the utility does not check the disk format, but assumes a block size of `1024` unless instructed otherwise.)

If you want to simply get the number of files, you might try something like

```
ls | wc -l
```

Comment: `ls | wc -l` will fail if there are files with a newline in the filename. This is more resilient: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf . | wc -c`

Comment: "if file names have a new line in them" ... _shudder_

Comment: As `man ls` will tell you, you can avoid control chars with `-b` (escapes them) or `-q` (omits them). So for counting, `ls -1q | wc -l` is safe and accurate for showing non-hidden files. `ls -1qA | wc -l` to count hidden files (but not `.` and `..`). I'm using `-1` instead of `-l` because that should be faster.

Answer (score 18):

[user4556274 has already answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/810564/295286) the *why*. My answer serves only to provide additional information for *how* to properly count files.

In the Unix community the general consensus is that [parsing the output of `ls` is a very very bad idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), since filenames can contain control characters or hidden characters. For example, due to a newline character in a filename, we have `ls | wc -l` tell us there's 5 lines in the output of `ls` (which  it does have), but in reality there's only 4 files in the directory.

```
$> touch  FILE$'\n'NAME                                                       
$> ls                                                                         
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  FILE?NAME
$> ls | wc -l
5
```

#### Method #1: find utility

The `find` command, which is typically used for working around parsing filenames, can help us here by printing the [inode number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Be it a directory or a file, it only has one unique inode number. Thus, using `-printf "%i\n"` and excluding `.` via `-not -name "."` we can have an accurate count of the files. (Note the use of `-maxdepth 1` to prevent recursive descending into subdirectories)

```
$> find  -maxdepth 1 -not -name "." -print                                    
./file2.txt
./file1.txt
./FILE?NAME
./file3.txt
$> find  -maxdepth 1 -not -name "." -printf "%i\n" | wc -l                    
4
```

#### Method #2 : globstar

Simple, quick, and mostly portable way:

```
$ set -- * 
$ echo $#
228
```

`set` command is used to set positional parameters of the shell ( the `$<INTEGER>` variables, as in `echo $1` ). This is often used to work around `/bin/sh` limitation of lacking arrays. A version that performs extra checks can be found in [Gille's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90152/85039) over on Unix&Linux.

In shells that support arrays, such as `bash`, we can use

```
items=( dir/* )
echo ${#items[@]}
```

as proposed by [steeldriver in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810563/why-does-ls-l-count-more-files-than-me/810707#comment1225655_810707).

Similar trick to `find` method which used `wc` and globstar can be used with `stat` to count inode numbers per line:

```
$> LC_ALL=C stat ./* --printf "%i\n" | wc -l                                          
4
```

An alternative approach is to use a wildcard in `for` loop. (Note, this test uses a different directory to test whether this approach descends into subdirectories, which it does not - 16 is the verified number of items in my `~/bin` )

```
$> count=0; for item in ~/bin/* ; do count=$(($count+1)) ; echo $count ; done | tail -n 1                                
16
```

#### Method #3: other languages/interpreters

Python can also deal with problematic filenames via printing the length of a list given my `os.listdir()` function (which is non-recursive, and will only list items in the directory given as argument).

```
$> python -c "import os ; print os.listdir('.')"                              
['file2.txt', 'file1.txt', 'FILE\nNAME', 'file3.txt']
$>  python -c "import os ; print(len(os.listdir('.')))"                    
4
```

#### See also

- [What's the most resource efficient way to count how many files are in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90106/85039)

Comment: In bash, another option would be to use an array e.g.  `items=( dir/* ); echo ${#items[@]}` (adding `shopt -s dotglob` to include hidden files).

Comment: Printing inode numbers makes it easy to filter hardlinks if desired, with `find | sort -u | wc -l`.

Comment: @steeldriver:  I think the bash-array method is unlikely to be faster.  If you want it to be recursive, you need to use `items=( dir/** )` (with `shopt -s globstar`), but bash doesn't take advantage of extra metadata from readdir, so it stats every directory entry to see if it is a directory itself.  Many filesystems do store the filetype in the directory entry, so readdir can return it without accessing the inodes.  (e.g. the latest non-default XFS has this, and I think ext4 has had it for longer.)  If you `strace` find, you'll see a lot fewer `stat` system calls than stracing bash.

Comment: Why not just use `print(len(os.listdir('.')))`? Fewer characters to type and also avoids accessing doubly-underscored attributes.

Comment: @edwinksl edited , thx

Comment: @PeterCordes, given as the array approach doesn't require running two external programs (thus going through fork/exec/link/load overhead twice, not to mention setting up the FIFOs for a pipeline), I'd expect it to be *considerably* faster than piping `ls` to `wc -l`... and at least in small directories (I don't have any huge ones on hand), experimental validation is bearing this out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yes, for small directories; I forgot to say that.  I meant to say that it doesn't scale well to large nested directory trees like `/usr`.  Even large single directories are probably fine; it's only the `**` that sucks.  `*` just needs the names and doesn't care about filetypes, so it doesn't have to stat everything.

Comment: *nod*, agreed. The large recursive case is one that `find` is well-optimized for.