# Move only the last 8 files in a directory to another directory

Tags: command-line, files, directory, mv, tail

I'm trying to move the last 8 files from the `Documents` directory to another directory, but I don't want to move them one-by-one to that specific directory. Is it possible to move them with a substitute of the `tail` command, but for directories instead of files? I mean I'd like to do so with something like `tail -8 ./Documents | mv ./Anotherdirectory` or with `mv tail -8 ./Documents ./Anotherdirectory`.

In fact, I'm looking for a clever way I could move the last 8 files (as listed in `ls`) quickly (without typing out each name) to the other directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please write in English what your end goal is. It's not clear from your question. To move all files from one directory to another: `mv dir1/* dir2`.

Comment: do you mean something like... the last 8 files shown by `ls`?

Comment: @darksky It's because many files in the `Documents` directory are mixed up and not well organised. So, for instance, I have created `Curriculum_Vitae` directory in the `Documents` directory (i.e. ./Documents/Curriculum_Vitae) and I want to put all files related to the subject in that directory. However, there are a lot of those file and I don't want to move them one-by-one.

Comment: @Zanna Yes, exactly!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `for`, which loops over the files in an ordered way, and allows us to avoid parsing the output of `find` or `ls`, to avoid issues with spaces and other special characters in filenames. Many thanks to @muru for improving this :)

```
i=0; j=$(stat ~/Documents/* --printf "%i\n" | wc -l); for k in ~/Documents/*; do if (( (j - ++i) < 8 )); then echo mv -v "$k" ~/AnotherDirectory; fi; done
```

Test it first with `echo`, then remove `echo` to actually move the files.

As a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
j=$(stat ~/Documents/* --printf "%i\n" | wc -l )
for k in ~/Documents/*; do
  if (( (j - ++i) < 8 )); then
    echo mv -v -- "$k" ~/AnotherDirectory
  fi
done
```

again, remove `echo` after testing to move the files for real

#### Explanation

- `i=0` telling the shell to start iterating at 0
- `j=$(stat ~/Documents/* --printf "%i\n" | wc -l )` this is setting the variable `j` to an integer equal to the total number of files in the directory. Thanks to [Serg's answer to my own question on how to count files reliably no matter what characters their names contain](https://askubuntu.com/a/810707/527764)
- `do if (( (j - ++i) < 8 ))` for each iteration of the loop, test whether the outcome of `j` minus the number of times the loop has been run is less than 8 and if it is then
- `mv -v -- "$k" ~/AnotherDirectory` move the file to the new directory

Comment: `[[ $((j-$((++i)))) -lt 8 ]]` == `(( (j - ++i) < 8 ))`

Comment: @muru I will remove some parentheses & thanks, but `<` will go wrong if there are ten files or more because it means `sorts before` not `less than` and 10 will sort before 8.

Comment: Nope. `(( ))` is arithmetic context. `<` compares integers in that context, 8 < 10.

Comment: @muru oh I am awake now (5 and a half hours behind & more haha) obviously you're right & thank you

Comment: i have a folder with a huge amount of files, ls would not work. This command also does not work as requested. I am using it and kill it after a while as it moves all files and does not stop. I have managed to move hundreds and then I have to CTRL + C to avoid flooding the other folder

Comment: @Bizmate that shouldn't happen. You can post a new question with details about your problem and hopefully someone will be able to help you with it. I'd be happy to take a look

Answer (score 3):

You can do things like this using command substitution. In Bash:

```
mv $(ls -d [sort options] source/* | tail -n8) destination
```

The `$(command)` will run whatever is enclosed in it and substitute the text output into the outer command. That `ls` command will print the path to each file in the source directory sorted according the the flags you specify, one per line, so `tail` can just take the last few. Thus the above would expand to

```
mv source/file1 source/file2 source/file3 ... source/file8 destination
```

You can just run `ls -d [sort options] source/* | tail -n8` to see what files it will copy.

Depending on how you're ordering the output of `ls` and the file naming, you may be able to do what you're looking for more simply just using some variant of `mv source/name_* destination` to copy everything starting with "name_" to the destination directory.

**EDIT:**
The above breaks when there are spaces in the file names. A more complicated alternative that addresses this would be

```
ls -d1 [sort options] source/* | tail -n8 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs --null mv -t destination
```

though it still makes use of parsing `ls` output to get sorting in any order that isn't alphabetical.

Answer (score 1):

similar to t-mager's suggestion, you can use ls sort options and grab the last 8 files into a list and these are your files:

`1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9`

use the following command:
`` for n in `ls|tail -8`; do mv $n ~/temp; done ``

Comment: [Not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Zanna, why not? besides the original backticks problem, this command simply moves that last 8 files form 1 directory to another and is easy to understand.

Comment: It will break if there are spaces, newlines etc in filesnames. See the link for why I spent so much effort on my own answer when parsing `ls` is much more obvious...

Answer (score 0):

I find that this works too:
 `ls -1 [sort options] | tail -n2 | xargs -I {} -n 1 echo "mv \"{}\" ../t2/"`

Of course, the echo has to be removed:
  `ls -1 | tail -n2 | xargs -I {} -n 1 mv "{}" ../t2/`

The `"{}"` can be replaced with `'{}'`
Actually, as a final experiment, removing the (double) quotes works too. Surprising, but tested.