# What is the difference between ls and ls -l?

Tags: ls

I am very new to linux. While practicing the file management commands I have found that 'ls' and 'ls -l' gives 2 different outputs but they appears to be related to each other.

[image]

The content of the file hello.sh is **echo "Hello world"**

can anyone explain what does 'ls -l' gives as output.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: -l ~= long or "*-l     use a long listing format*" as can be read with `man ls` which will show you the reference manual page for `ls`. `man` allows you to search...

Comment: Type **man ls**.  It will tell you all about ls.

Comment: @pomsky
The link that u have provided states that--> "As mentioned earlier -l will show the entries as a long list along with various attributes" but in the directory first-dir I have only 1 file named hello.sh. So why is it showing 'total-4'?

Comment: Refer to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/810563/480481