# Forbidden: Unable to access VirtualHost URL in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2, ntfs, virtualhost

I just create new virtual host from path `/media/rahul/142E875C2E873630/xampp/htdocs/` that's the path of my mounted drive in ubuntu. Now when I created virtual host of this url its created successfully but now, when I am opening my host url it's showing `403 Forbidden`.

My `shared.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName shared
ServerAlias www.shared.com
DocumentRoot /media/rahul/142E875C2E873630/xampp/htdocs
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AuthType None
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory /media/rahul/142E875C2E873630/xampp/htdocs/>
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AuthType None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I have also add `url` in host file but still getting same error.

Is there any idea why this happening?

About Permissions:

[image]

Comment: Check permissions on the folders. Check the apache user (www-data?) has access to the destination folder.

Comment: i just set permissions with `sudo chmod -R 777 htdocs` but still same error

Comment: Whether the parent directories are readable for www-data?

Comment: i did not getting your point..actually  this is my windows directory of xampp and i am trying to create virtual host of this directory so that i can do changes in the same directory whether i am using windows or ubuntu

Comment: even i am not able to access another `sda4` directory if i am setting the path of those directory `/media/rahul/One/shared`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about the permissions. The system user (www-data) who runs your web server must have read [permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) to the folder `htdocs` and to the whole path to this folder.

Here I will describe three ways how that could be done:

1. The short way - just give enough permissions;
2. The proper (according to my knowledge) way - using terminal and `/etc/fstab`;
3. The easiest proper way - using GUI tool `Disks`.

---

### 1. Just give enough permissions

For this purpose open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo chmod 755 /media/rahul/
```

Or give these permissions through `Nemo` as it is shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpeSU.png) from the question. Please remember `777` is not the best choice.

---

### 2. Make the partition part of the static file system tree: `/etc/fstab`

Specify static mount point and mount the partition (device) with [right permissions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mount.8.html#contenttoc25) through `/etc/fstab`:

**1.** Create an appropriate mount point - open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/shared
```

**2.** Find the necessary preliminary information:

- Find the partition (device) identification. Type `sudo blkid` and recognize your target partition (device). Let's assume it is **`/dev/sda4`** with `UUID=142E875C2E873630`.
- Find your user's `uid` (user-id) and `gid` (group-id). In the terminal type: **`id`**. The result shall looks something like: `uid=1000(rahul) gid=1000(rahul) groups=1000(rahul),..`

  For further, more [complicated permissions settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www) the data for some other users will be needed, for example **`id www-data`** will return: `uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data),...`

**3.** Edit your `/etc/fstab` file as root (using `sudo`) and add new line:

- When the device/partition is formatted under **`NTFS`** this new line could be:

  ```
  /dev/sda4 /mnt/shared ntfs uid=1000,gid=33,nls=utf8,umask=0022,fmask=111 0 0
  ```

  Where:

  - `/dev/sda4` the partition (device) - by `/dev` location or `UUID` - that contain a file system.
  - `/mnt/shared` the location where the above partition (device) will be mounted.
  - `ntfs` the type of the target device file system.
  - `uid=1000,gid=1000` will set ownership permissions for user and group `rahul`; `uid=1000,gid=33` will set ownership permissions for user `rahul` and group `www-data`.
  - `nls=utf8` means [Use UTF-8 for converting file names](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html#contenttoc25).
  - `umask=0022` will set the [permissions](http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm) for all folders to `drwxr-xr-x` or octal `755`.
  - `fmask=111` will set the permissions for all files to `-rw-rw-rw-` or octal `666`.
- When the partition (device) is formatted under **`ext4`** this new line could be:

  ```
  /dev/sda4 /mnt/shared ext4 default 0 0
  ```

  Ant the permissions of its content can be further managed as usual - `chown`, `chmod`, etc.

**4.** Save the edits of `/etc/fstab`, and reload it: `sudo mount -a`.

**Important note!** If this is an external (USB) device, if it is unplugged, an error will be appeared. The solution is: 1) Go to Recovery mode, 2) edit `/etc/fstab` and 3) comment (`#`) the line described above.

---

### 3. Make the partition part of the static file system tree: `Disks`

**1.** Open Dash and type `Disks`:

[image]

**2.** Find your target device and select `Edit Mount Options`:

[image]

**3.** Edit Mount Options and click on `OK`:

[image]

**4.** Mount the device - click on the `Play` button:

[image]

---

### Further steps

**1.** Find the new location of your `htdocs` folder. It should be something as:

```
/mnt/shared/xampp/htdocs
```

**2.** Edit your `shared.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName shared
    ServerAlias www.shared.com
    DocumentRoot /mnt/shared/xampp/htdocs
    <Directory />
        #etc ...
    </Directory>
    <Directory /mnt/shared/xampp/htdocs/>
        #etc ...
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined   
</VirtualHost>
```

**3.** Restart Apache2 and try to access your site.

---

### Sources and further reading

- [**Working example with an NTFS device**](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24400179/)
- [Why are the default permissions for /media/username root:root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392154/why-are-the-default-permissions-for-media-username-rootroot)
- [Permission problem on /media/user folder prevents me from accessing external media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806762/permission-problem-on-media-user-folder-prevents-me-from-accessing-external-med)
- [Accessing my NTFS folder with Apache](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2033983)
- [Mount NTFS Partition on Startup in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23843/mount-ntfs-partition-on-startup-in-ubuntu)
- [Fstab - make default permission 755](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176441)
- [How do I correctly mount a NTFS partition in /etc/fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab)
- [How can I get octal file permissions from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line)
- ["dmask" and "fmask" mount options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848/dmask-and-fmask-mount-options)
- [How to mount a new drive on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup)